# Does Google make money from 'Google Pay' for online purchases?

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, payment

Does Google charge anything for using Google Pay and letting pay through it **for online transaction** in web of mobile app?

According to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/setup), merchant, or PSP that would like to enable Google Pay as a payment method should register first for this service and accept a merchant ID that will be used for the further payment transactions. But does google charge a fee for  the registration or ongoing use?

When someone in the payment chain charge money eventually the cost coverage comes from the merchant or the end-user-customer

Comment: Can you add country tag. This varies

Comment: *Everyone* in the credit card processing chain charges the merchant something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google pay delegates payment processing to other providers who are charging the merchants fees already.
They do not charge their own fees (from https://developers.google.com/pay/api/faq):

> **Does Google Pay charge any fees?**
>
> Google Pay doesn't additionally charge users, merchants, and developers additional fees to use the Google Pay API for payments. Merchants, specifically, continue to pay processing fees to their payment processor.

Given that Google's business is about monetising user data for advertising, there are two ways that that they likely benefit:

1. Knowledge of what people are actually buying is very valuable from an advertising perspective.
2. General stickiness within the Google product ecosystem, so they can keep collecting data on people.

Comment: I would say Google Pay does not charge any fees **yet**. _-_ Odds are they may start charging fees in the future. Advertising is only one of the strategies Google uses to get paid for the services it offers, another strategy seen (with for instance Google maps)  is a modified freemium model that starts out completely free but once there is sufficient market penetration the free tier allowances get reduced and paid for options are created and required for larger/commercial use of their services.

Comment: I summarized some of the advantages for Google from this product in this article: https://medium.com/@guyroth/how-gafa-threats-the-existing-payment-industry-980d6708c496